# Data Validation Custom Formula with OR

Tags: excel, validation, formula

I am trying to create data validation for a range of cells, used for our timesheets - the idea is that the cell can be any number divisible by 0.25, or a phrase e.g. OFF, SICK, etc.

Using the custom formula `=E12="OFF"` - as expected, I can put OFF in the cell.

Using the custom formula `=MOD(E12,0.25)=0` - as expected, I can put any number divisible by 0.25.

Following this logic, using `=OR(E12="OFF",MOD(E12,0.25)=0)` - I would expect to be able to have either OFF or any number divisible by 0.25 - the numbers are fine but it will not allow "OFF".

On the other hand, `=OR(E12="OFF",E12="SICK")` - both phrases work and nothing else.

Also, `=OR(MOD(E12,0.25)=0,E12=1.1)` - I can put anything divisible by 0.25 or the value 1.1.

So I can't understand why a mix of both the modulus as well as specific phrases will not work as expected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

N.B. - Overall, ideally, I would like `0 < E12:E30 < 12` as well as `E12:E30` to be able to be `"OFF"`, `"SICK"`, `"SMP"`, `"SPP"`, `"HP"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get an error on `MOD(E12,0.25)=0` when the cell is text and an error will cause the data validation to become FALSE overall, so you need to split the path:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(E12),MOD(E12,0.25)=0,E12="OFF")
```

What you want Overall:

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(E12),OR(MOD(E12,0.25)=0,AND(E12>0,E12<12)),ISNUMBER(MATCH(E12,{"SICK", "SMP", "SPP", "HP"},0)))
```

Comment: Star - strange as I thought that would be covered by the fact you have put an OR but you have solved my issue. Thanks.

Comment: If this worked, please consider marking correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.